# Saving User Input Information

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a web app that I want to allow users to submit and save their information for their profile. There are two sets of information that I am trying to save, but they're not being stored in the same set in my firebase database. How can I get my function to work properly? I have provided screenshots and the code below:

Submit Data Function and variables:

```
var userEntry = firebase.database()
.ref('/Studiopick/studios/users');

var stuEntry = firebase.database()
.ref('/Studiopick/studios/studioId/stuInfo');

document.getElementById('studioForm')
.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

document.getElementById('studioForm')
.addEventListener('submit', submitStu);

//Register A New User
function submitForm() {

    // Get values
    firstName = getInputVal('firstName');
    lastName = getInputVal('lastName');
    email = getInputVal('email');
    phoneNumber = getInputVal('phoneNumber');
    password = getInputVal('password');

    // Submit Profile Info
    saveUser(firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber, password);
    document.getElementById('studioForm');
}

//Register A New Studio
function submitStu() {

    // Get values
    address = getInputVal('address');
    country = getInputVal('country');
    state = getInputVal('state');
    city = getinputVal('city');
    zip = getInputVal('zip');
   

    // Submit Profile Info
    saveStu(address, country, state, city, zip);
    document.getElementById('studioForm');
}

// Function to get get form values
function getInputVal(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
}
  
// Save new user to firebase
function saveUser(email, fullName, phoneNumber, userName, password) {
var newUserEntry = userEntry.push();
    newUserEntry.set({
        email:email,
        fullName:fullName,
        phoneNumber:phoneNumber,
        userName:userName,
        password:password,
        last_login : Date.now()

    });
}

// Save new/update studio to firebase
function saveStu(address, country, state, city, zip) {
    var newStuEntry = stuEntry.push();
        newStuEntry.set({
            address:address,
            country:country,
            state:state,
            city:city,
            zip:zip,
    
    });
}
```

Firebase Database JSON:

```
{
  "Studiopick": {
    "artists": {
      "users": {
        "-N7MP9BpXpmR2ZePAdHz": {
          "email": "1234@gmail.com",
          "fullName": "Lil Grmln",
          "last_login": 1658250109589,
          "password": "September19!",
          "phoneNumber": "123-456-7890",
          "userName": "Test "
        }
      }
    },
    "studios": {
      "studioId": {
        "stuInfo": {
          "address: "studio address",
          "city": "studio city",
          "state": "studio state",
          "country": "studio country",
          "zip": "studio zip",
          "studio": "studio name"
      },
      "users": {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what shape are you looking for in your firebase db?

Comment: What do you mean by shape?

Comment: Apparently your code is not saving the data how you'd like it to be saved. Can you edit your question (there's a link right under it for that purpose) to show us how you'd like it to be saved (preferably as actual JSON as text, rather than a screenshot)?

Comment: Apparently your code is not saving the data how you'd like it to be saved. Can you show us how you'd like it to be saved (preferably as actual JSON as text, rather than a screenshot)?

Comment: remove __.set__ use  push() only it will generate key too, you can't use push and set together.           var newStuEntry = stuEntry;
        newStuEntry.push({
            address:address,
            country:country,
            state:state,
            city:city,
            zip:zip,
    
    });

Comment: just changed the screenshot to json code

Comment: I used it together in a different function and it worked fine. Look at the artist user info in my JSON text above.

Comment: try answer given below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**remove **set()** use  **push()** only if you want to add and generate new key and child**

```
// Save new user to firebase
function saveUser(email, fullName, phoneNumber, userName, password) {
var newUserEntry = userEntry;
    newUserEntry.push({
        email:email,
        fullName:fullName,
        phoneNumber:phoneNumber,
        userName:userName,
        password:password,
        last_login : Date.now()

    });
}

// Save new/update studio to firebase
function saveStu(address, country, state, city, zip) {
    var newStuEntry = stuEntry;
        newStuEntry.push({
            address:address,
            country:country,
            state:state,
            city:city,
            zip:zip,
    
    });
}
```

if you want to set data in only in these two so you can replace the **.push()** with **.set()**

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Ok. what's your email?

Comment: sent it through.

Comment: got it lemme solve and post it here